# Using ContentByteUtils for raw PDF manipulation

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext

This is a follow up question to:

[Programmatically change the color of a black box in a PDF file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960740/programmatically-change-the-color-of-a-black-box-in-a-pdf-file)

I have a pdf I created in Illustrator that has basically a black shape in the middle of the page and nothing else. I need to change the color of that shape dynamically.

From the response to the post above I am using iTextSharp (.NET C#) to get the raw contents of the PDF through ContentByteUtils.GetContentBytesForPage() and changing the color at the raw level.

Problem is that I can't find any way of saving the results back into either the original PDF or a new PDF file via iTextSharp. I'm currently stuck with a byte array of the raw contents but need to figure out how to save.

Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `ContentByteUtils.GetContentBytesForPage()`?

I would use:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
byte[] content = reader.GetPageContent(pageNumber);
// do stuff with content
reader.SetPageContent(pageNumber, content);
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs)) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! SetPageContent is exactly what I was looking for! Saved my life!